# png image pixelated in sprite

Tags: css, image, png

our existing app uses a single image for the chevron icon below. I am trying to move this into a sprite but it seems pixelated when i save the image, place into the PSD and save for web (as a 24 bit PNG)

Smooth as a single image

[image: Smooth PNG]

Pixelated when part of a sprite.

[image: Rough PNG]
Could something be happening when i save the image from the browser ? or maybe when i place the image into a PSD file ?

Here is a simple fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CmE2h/2/

```
<ul>
<li class="image">Image</li>
<li class="sprite">Sprite
<span>
    </span>
</li>    
</ul>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: first of all.. the icon in the app seems to have other kind of effects on it, like inset shadow or something. Use your browser's inspector to see if there are any styles applied on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've made a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CmE2h/2/

Answer (score 0):

..It's definately your image. It's pixelated because your png sprite is pixelated. That's your problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJHO4.png